# finding the minimum and maximum in tuples (database)

Tags: database, relational-database, relational-algebra

Consider a relation R where the number of the tuples of R is N. how can I find the minimum
and maximum possible sizes (in tuples) for the result relation
produced by the following relational algebra expressions? please help..

```
(1) σA=5 AND B=5(R)     
(2) ΠA,B(R)
```

(A,B is the random names of the attribute)

σ means select and Π is project...

Answer (score 0):

"how can I find ..."

Restrict filters out tuples from the input.  Can it filter out zero tuples in total ?  Less than zero tuples ?  Can it filter out N tuples in total ?  More than N ?

Similar reasoning for projection.

Answer (score 0):

(1) σA=5 AND B=5(R)

max: N, min: 0

max case: all the tuples in R have A=5 and B=5

min case: none tuple in R has A=5 and B = 5

(2) ΠA,B(R)

max: N, min: 1

max case: R has no 2 tuples t1, t2, letting (t1.A=t2.A and t1.B=t2.B)

min case: all the tuples in R has the same value in A and B, then ΠA,B will delete the duplicate tuples, only 1 left